# Excel VBA - Prevent All User Interaction In Cells Except Through Data Validation List

Tags: vba, excel, validation, excel-2010

*Please read my edits below the problem description.*

I have a worksheet with cells (in column 4) that are edited through a data validation dropdown with multiple selection, using the below code coupled with the data validation list. Currently, the user can backspace items which, as expected, causes an alert to appear that warns the user not to edit the cell. However, when that alert is canceled, the cell is populated by multiple versions of what was in it prior to the attempt at backspacing. In addition to backspace, they can use the delete key to delete items.

How would I alter the VBA code to prevent users from doing ANYTHING except choosing items from the data validation dropdown (and choosing again to remove the item as currently occurs)? They should not be able to edit, delete, or otherwise manipulate the cells in any way.

Basically, I want to prevent every action for cells in column 4 except the existing entry and removal via data validation dropdown list. Protecting the workbook will not work because the cells would have to be unlocked for the data validation to work.

**EDIT:** Could I include something like this pseudocode `Application.OnKey Key:="{BACKSPACE}", DO NOTHING`? If so, where would that be included? I tried adding this above the `Worksheet_Change()`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", ""
End Sub
```

This had no effect.

This piece of code, added under `If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler`, causes the delete button to stop working, but using backspace still causes the same problems.

```
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D150")) Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    MsgBox "Please don't clear this cell."
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

Full code without edits:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            If newVal = "" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Ar = Split(oldVal, ";" & vbCrLf)
                strVal = ""
                For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                    Debug.Print strVal
                    Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                    If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                        'do not include this item
                        strVal = strVal
                        lCount = 1
                    Else
                        strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ";" & vbCrLf
                    End If
                Next i
                If lCount > 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 3)
                Else
                    Target.Value = strVal & newVal
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: By removal do you selection of another value from the validation list or delete populates with a default value that is part of the list?

Comment: I'd really need to see more of your worksheet to understand what isn't working for you. You can unprotect specific cells when you protect the worksheet - that would let users alter only the data validation cells. At that point, there's a whole lot you can do to ensure that only specific values are entered in that cell. Data validation will do just that - not sure what you mean when you say the cell is populated by multiple versions of what was in it prior to backspacing.